# ValueError with resize numpy array method

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

When I write the below code inside a single cell in Jupyter Notebook, it doesn't throw any error:

[image: No error]

However, if I write the code in two cells as shown below, it throws an error:

[image: Throws error]

Can someone please explain the reason for this issue?

Comment: I think most probably it is because the variable is defined locally in each cell. You can't use variable defined in one cell into another cell

Comment: The display of `a` in the first cell is the other reference the error is talking about. Because `resize` works in-place, it is picky about what can be done with the array.